# Clearing JTextArea not working

Tags: java, swing, jlist, jtextarea

I'm trying to clear a text area that has something written on it. 
I've been trying to use the repaint() method, since I think that kind of resets the text area, but it hasn't been working.

I'm using the text area along with a list. When members of the list are clicked, the said members will display on the text area. So when they are "deselected", I need the previously-written members to disappear from the text area.

Here is the code for the valueChanged, which is where things happen:

```
public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e)
{
        Object source = e.getSource();
        int[] indices = songList.getSelectedIndices();
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#0.00");

        Song[] selection = new Song[indices.length];
        for(int i = 0; i < indices.length; i++)
        {
            selection[i] = songCollection[indices[i]];
        }
        if(e.getValueIsAdjusting() == false)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < selection.length; i++)
            {
                textArea.repaint(); //Shouldn't this work?
                textArea.append(selection[i].getTitle() + " " + selection[i].getArtist() + "    " + df.format(selection[i].getPrice()) + "\n" );

            }

        }               

}
```

PS, I'm pretty new to Stack Overflow, so if I did something wrong, feel free to tell me.

Comment: RTFM..`repaint` doesn't clear the component. For more information, please see [How to Use Text Areas](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textarea.html).

Comment: `repaint()` does not change the text in the `Document` of the `JTextArea`, it merely repaints the component. You are looking for `textArea.setText("");`

Answer (score 4):

According to [`JTextComponent#setText`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#setText%28java.lang.String%29),

> Sets the text of this `TextComponent` to the specified text. If the text
>   is `null` or empty, has the effect of simply deleting the old text. When
>   text has been inserted, the resulting caret location is determined by
>   the implementation of the caret class.

So, to clear text from a `JTextArea` component, either do `setText(null)`, or `setText("")`.

Answer (score 2):

As said above.

The setText(" ")  also works for text fields btw.